# How to detect home key event

Tags: android, key, android-homebutton

In order to finish android activity when holding Vol UP + home.
The home button is not detected as key event:
I already cheched with onkey onkeyevent but only back button is detected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect or override home event. It's just not possible due to security reasons. You have to play with onPause/onStop callbacks